# Is there System.Runtime.Intrinsics for .NET framework?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I can only see System.Runtime.Intrinsics for .NET Core 3.0 (which is a preview). Is there similar dll for .NET Framework?

Comment: For such, your best channel is GitHub https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues

Comment: thanks. ill try. however - if you were working on the Core, why would you be interested answering questions about the Framework? I wouldn't.

Comment: _if you were working on the Core, why would you be interested answering questions about the Framework?_

It's the same team at Microsoft that works on both .NET Core and .NET Framework.

Comment: The ['Vector<T> struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?view=netcore-2.2) is available in the .NETFramework.  Be sure to use the Nuget package, it was considered too risky to include it with the default install.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors/4.5.0

Comment: @hans vectors aren't enough. I am trying to replicate intel algorithm from this white paper and see if it works faster w avx2 and/or avx512 : https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/sha-256-implementations-paper.pdf

Comment: P. S. Unless someone can prove the. Net framework sha256 cng implementation about same fast including avx512 (because this whole task started with premise that sha on avx512 is 40% faster than on avx2)

Comment: System.Numerics.Vectors [uses AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34532449/17034).  If you want to prove anything then .NETCore surely ought to be good enough.

Comment: I will post the results and we see whats what firsthand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately the hardware intrinsics feature is only supported on .NET Core. It isn't available on .NET Framework.
You can get .NET Core 3.0 Preview 1 from https://aka.ms/netcore3download.
Note that you no longer need to reference the System.Runtime.Intrinsics package to use the feature. The APIs are available by default when targeting netcoreapp3.0.

Comment: Thanks I decided to use c++/cli project mixed with native code where intrinsics are available for x64.. All is working. Now I just need to port Intel "fast sha256" code... Phew.. Wish me luck kuck

Comment: P. S. I need production code soon. I can't use alpha software. Even beta won't do.

Comment: Any idea if intrinsics are likely to *ever* appear in .NET Framework?